# How to calculate the offset() of an <li> relative to its parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<li>` which is nested inside a containing `<ul>`, what I would like is to calculate the offset. But have the top-left corner of the `<ul>` be `0, 0`.

So my HTML is:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 760px; height: 760px; overflow: hidden;">
    <ul style="width: 2000px; height: 2000px; min-height: 2000px; position: relative;">
        <li style="position: relative; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my current jQuery is:

```
thePos = $('ul li').offset();
alert('X = '+thePos.left+', Y = 'thePos.top);
```

However, this is returning offsets that are not `0, 0`. I guess it is calculating the offset relative to the edge of the document instead of the parent container.

How can I get around this?

Thanking you.

*note: `position()` doesn't retrieve the right numbers either :(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting:

```
thePosX = $('ul li').css('left');
thePosY = $('ul li').css('top');
```

Instead of:

```
thePos = $('ul li').css('left');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using `position()` instead of `offset()`.

From the jQuery docs:

> The .offset() method allows us to
>   retrieve the current position of an
>   element relative to the document.
>   Contrast this with .position(), which
>   retrieves the current position
>   relative to the offset parent.

Comment: Hey Mark, cheers but `position()` retrieves the same numbers :(

Comment: Change on li position:relative to position:absolute. And Mark is right here - offset always calculates from browser top and left border - use position instead.